# Magento 2 send data using ajax in custom form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.3

How can i accomplish it?
Here is my controller:

```
    public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

    if ($data) {
        $model = $this->callbackInterfaceFactory->create();
        $model->setData($data);
        try {
            $this->callbackRepository->create()->save($model);
            /** massage on email */
            $massage = '';
            if ($this->scopeConfig->getValue('dukir_callback_configuration/email/enable', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE) == '1') {
                $this->sendmail->sendmail($data);
                $massage = ', and sent to the mail';
            }

            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Successfully saved' . $massage));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath($this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            return $resultRedirect->setPath($this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you implement ajax code from where you want to call this controller action?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I try to understand how to do it

Comment: Do you mean you want ajax code how to call this controller action?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes, and what should i change in controller?

Comment: in controller you need to do code according to your requirement.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya controller, which i provided working well. Need only add ajax call

Comment: I provide the code, how to call ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

To call the controller action from phtml, you used this code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var formurl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('Vendor/Extension/Action'); ?>'; 
      jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: formurl,
          data:{variable:variable},
          beforeSend: function()
          {
              //do Logic before ajax request start
          }, 
          success: function(transport) 
          {
              //Do Logic when sucess comes
          },
          error: function() 
          {
              //Do Logic when error into request
          }
     });
  }
</script>
```